# Angular / send data to component while calling it from template

Tags: angular, components, send

I have component Main. Inside "Main" component I insert "SideBar" component.

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
```

Is it possible somehow to send data to that sidebar from Main while calling it ?

```
<app-sidebar>
maybe put data here ? 
</app-sidebar>
```

Comment: Have you looked into using inputs? https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that using @Input(). This link should be helpful [Component Interactions](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

Using @Input()
like @Input() isDropdownClicked: boolean